# List DoubleClick EventListener

Tags: actionscript-3, list, event-handling

I am using the list component in my AS3 program. I would like to add a doubleclick event listener, however this doesn't seem to work:

```
m_list.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, OnDoubleClick);
```

Do I need to do something special with adding click listeners to a list? Do I need to add a listener to each cell inside of the list or something?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you try `m_list.doubleClickEnabled = true`?

Comment: Yeah that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
m_list.addEventListener(ListEvent.ITEM_DOUBLE_CLICK, OnDoubleClick);
```